# C# - Retrieve Largest MySQL Column Value, Increment by 1, and use in INSERT statement

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-insert, sqldatareader

I'm using c#, MySQL and visual studio 2015.

I have a:

- Database called 'cp_users'
- Table called 'users'
- Column called 'account_no'

The account_no column is int(11) and primary key.

I am simply trying to get the value of the highest account number, add 1 to it and then use the new value in my statement to insert the new user data, thereby ensuring that the account numbers never conflict.

For info:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mcon.ConnectionString = "datasource=166.XXX.XXX.XXX;port=3306;initial catalog=cp_users; username=XXXXXX;password=XXXXXX";
    }
```

Code I'm having trouble with:

```
            if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "" && textBox4.Text != "" && textBox5.Text != "" && textBox6.Text != "" && listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
                             {
                                mcon.Open();
                                //Upload New User Information to 'users' Database
                                try
                                {

        //CODE TO RECALL LARGEST ACCOUNT NUMBER AS reader3 VALUE,
        //INCREASE IT BY 1, ASSIGN IT AS A STRING
        //FOR USE BELOW (NOT WORKING)

                                    MySqlCommand mda3 = new MySqlCommand();
                                    mda3.Connection = mcon;
                                    mda3.CommandText = "SELECT max(account_no) value FROM users";
                                    MySqlDataReader reader3 = mda3.ExecuteReader();
                                    reader3 = reader3++;


        //UPLOAD NEW USER DATA INCLUDING 'reader3' VALUE FOR 'account_no'

                                    MySqlCommand mda2 = new MySqlCommand();
                                    mda2.Connection = mcon;
                                    mda2.CommandText = ("insert into cp_users.users(account_no, first_name, last_name, email_1, company_industry, user_password) values('" + reader3 + "','" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + listBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox5.Text + "');");
                                    MySqlDataReader reader2 = mda2.ExecuteReader();
                                    mcon.Close();

                                    this.Hide();
                                    Form2 frm4 = new Form2();
                                    frm4.ShowDialog();
                                    MessageBox.Show("Registration Successful - You can now login to our Desktop, Web and App Interfaces", "Welcome to ConnectPlanet");

                            }
                                    catch
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("New Registration Failed - We're Sorry, Please Contact Customer Support", "Oops!");
                                mcon.Close();
                            }
```

Any advice is appreciated, I'm guessing this is simple for someone with more experience but I cant seem to find the answer online or in my (Small) book collection.

Comment: After following the answer below, take a bit of your time and search about "Sql Injection"

Comment: Oh my God....I spent hours working on that!! Oh well, another lesson learned. :) Thank you very much. I'll look at Sql Injection tomorrow Steve, thanks, its late here...goodnight.

Comment: @Dmur - You might want to consider using a `finally` block to close the database connection

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. see :[Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    account_no   INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email_1 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    company_industry VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    user_password VARCHAR(128) NOT NUL
);
```

So you don't even need to specify the id column when inserting data :

```
insert into cp_users.users(first_name, last_name, email_1, company_industry, user_password) values( ....
```